# Store an array field in a new table column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this

```
| id |         amenities        |      owner     |
|----|--------------------------|----------------|
|  1 | {tv, hairdryer, iron}    | Chris Houghton |
|  2 | {tv, aircondition, iron} | Matt Quinn     |
```

I want to store the car table values in a new column "amenity_name" of another table "Amenity" but without UNNEST.
Here is what I tried so far

```
UPDATE public."Amenity" set amenity_name = (
SELECT amenities
FROM public."Listing" as l 
   cross join regexp_split_to_table(l.amenities , ',') as amenity_name
);
```

What is wrong with this code.

Comment: There is a way to define [unnest-like functions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Array_Unnest) for Postgresql versions <= 8.3.

Comment: Table definitions of source and target, your version of Postgres and the reason why to avoid unnest would help tremendously.